# How do I the add path to a 3rd party library? - Eclipse/Arduino

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, arduino, avr

This is my first time coding in C++ and I have no experience with compiler languages.

I am creating an Arduino project using Eclipse. I want include a 3rd party library. I need to add the path of the library in Eclipse but don't know how. The documentation I found said that I should look at the following:

Project --> Properties --> C/C++ General --> Paths and Symbols

but as you can see in the image Paths and Symbols does not exist. I used the the filter bar to search for Paths and did not get any relevant results. The libraries tab also does not let me add the package in any manner.

I think this is because Arduino uses an AVR compiler and not the cross gcc toolchain. If I create a normal C++ package I can add the path to another library. However, I have not yet figured out how to get it to compile for the Arduino.

How can I add the path to the Arduino project direct eclipse to the 3rd party library that I am using?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want this? `Right Click on "project"`->`Properties`->`C/C++ General`->`Processor Include Paths, Macros etc..`->`GNU C++`->`CDT User Settings`->`Add`

Comment: I am not seeing Processor Include Paths anywhere. I did find add PATH under the Linked Resources tab. However, I am still uncertain why parts mentioned in the official documentation are missing.

Comment: You should have "C/C++ Build" tab as well. It looks like you have some wrong or unsupported project type.

Comment: Which eclipse version are you using? And on which platform is it?

Comment: Also, make sure you right click on the MAIN project then go to properties from the bottom of the list.

Comment: I am using Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) and was looking at the main.

Comment: You are likely missing some plugins installed

Comment: I am really new to C++ so I don't understand this entirely. What appears to be the problem is that I am using a default template (specifically the Arduino Plugin). This does not include the Cross GCC toolchain. Therefore when looking through the project properties many things are missing. This includes "C/C++ Build" and the PATH variables. If I create a normal C++ project I am able to see everything as expected and amend the PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be really simple. In short you do not need to add the path of the library to eclipse.

```
//If you use:
<header.hpp> //Eclipse looks at the current directory
//but you could instead say
<path-to-header/header.hpp>
```

This eliminates the need to add the path to eclipse via the methods mentioned by everyone else

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution, I've installed oxygen 3a and here are the steps:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPvRY.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVU0n.jpg
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkMdL.jpg
4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbzFs.jpg
5. https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3fS9.jpg

I'm sure you can take over from here.